# Ciclo For Each - Combinado o Compuesto para consolidar registros

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes, tengo una tabla donde registro informacion de las personas por dia, en mi tabla se registra dia a dia, ahora me solicitan que esta informacion la presente en una sola fila con una columna por cada dia, presento el nombre, ingreso del lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado, domingo. Mi problema esta que no he podido indicarle que me consolide en un solo registro en una tabla nueva que hice, mi codigo es el siguiente, trabajo con dataset y es visual basic net.

Lleno el tableadapter con los registros

```vb
dim aocodigo as string = string.empty
for each aoregistros in dataset.detalledecodigos
     aocodigo = aoregistros.codigo.trim.tostring()
     hago una busqueda con este codigo, para completar otra informacion
     if lo encontro 
        'inserto los registros
        aorowtabla = dataset.tblsemana.newblsemarow
        aorowtabla.codigo = aoregistros.codigo
        aorowtabla.fechapordia = aoregistro.fecha
        aorowtabl.montoingreso = aoregistro.ingresopordia
        'Agregar registro nuevo
        dataset.tblsemana.addtablesemanarow(aorowtabla)
     endif
next
```

Al terminar me lo hace bien, me incluye como ejemplo los doce registros que tuvo la persona en la semana, pero uno a uno, y necesito que sean un solo registro, o una sola linea como que tuviera en excel.

gracias

Comment: Buenas noches, estimado Toledano, disculpa la pregunta, como se hace para formatear la pregunta a como modificaste la mia, ya busque en la ayuda de la pagina, para la proxima presentarla de esta forma.

Comment: Para formatear como código, simplemente selecciona el texto y pulsa en el botón con las dos llaves `{}`